# How do i calculate this simple problem i have?

Tags: percentages

Product A has 10% tax and product B has 24% tax. 2 products cost together 50€ with tax included. Tax of two products sum together is 8€. What is the price of product A tax included?

Comment: I would start like this: Tax for $A$ is $ T_A = 0.1A$; Tax for $B$ is $T_B = 0.24B$. Then we know that $A+B=50$; $T_A + T_B = 8$. Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, transfer the information into equations

\begin{align}
1.1A + 1.24 B &= 50 \\
0.1A + 0.24B &= 8
\end{align}

And solve simultaneously.